# Checking current time is in between 00:00 - 1:00 AM EST , it must include 00.00 && 01:00 EST

Tags: bash, shell, unix

My script:

```
currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
if [[ "$currenttime" > "00:00" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "01:00" ]]; then
./mailscript1.sh
else
./mailscript2.sh
fi
```

here i wanted it should included 00:00 and 01:00 and should trigger mailscript1 for true, >= and <= is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use +%s (epoch format - seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to compare times. This will reflect time as complete numbers e.g. 1610621912 and so:

```
currenttime=$(date +$s)
if [[ "$currenttime" -ge "$(date -d "00:00" +%s)" && "$currenttime" -le "$(date -d "01:00" +%s)" ]]
then 
   ./mailscript1.sh
else
   ./mailscript2.sh
fi
```

As the expansion of the dates will be strings, use -le for less than or equal and -ge for greater than or equal.

Answer (score 0):

for a time being and a simple solution to fulfill above requirement.
currenthour=`date +%H`
Nexthour=`date -d '+1 hour' +%H`
currentmin=`date +%M`

if [[ $currenthour -eq "00" ]] && [[ $Nexthour == "01" ]] && [[ $currentmin -ge 0 && $currentmin -le 59 ]];then
./mailscript2.sh
else
./mailscript1.sh
fi